# How to accumulate the changes to an immutable object within a Java stream and get the final result when stream terminates

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Is there any way to express the following code with Java 8 streams and lambdas?

```
ImmutableObject immutable = new ImmutableObject();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    immutable = immutable.changeState(i);
}
return immutable;
```

ImmutableObject is just a trivial immutable object:

```
class ImmutableObject {
    private final int state;

    public ImmutableObject() {
        this(0);
    }

    public ImmutableObject(final int state) {
        this.state = state;

    }

    public ImmutableObject changeState(final int newState) {
        return new ImmutableObject(newState);
    }
}
```

I came up with this:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10).
       mapToObj(i -> immutable.changeState(i)).reduce((a, b) -> b).get()
```

but the result for each iteration is discarded - I can't not assign the result back to immutable reference since it is inside a lamba expression and should be (effectively) final.

Comment: You can use an IntStream

Comment: This will always throw NPE, `immutable` is not initialized before calling `changeState`

Comment: @JornVernee: correct, I will edit my question.

Comment: @Kelvin: I came up with this: IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10).mapToObj(i -> immutable.changeState(i)).reduce((a, b) -> b).get() but it doesn't work. I need to find how to "refresh" immutable reference within the lamda.

Comment: @jilt3d `rangeClosed(1, 10)` will count from 1 (inclusive) to 10 (inclusive), but your loop counts from 0 (inclusive) to 9 (inclusive). You want `range(0, 10)` to count from 0 (inclusive) to 10 (exclusive).

Comment: @Andreas: yep, that's correct too, I am just using a pseudo-code that I translate on-the-fly with my real code, and I do mistakes. Will correct that too, thanks.

Comment: How about `return new ImmutableObject(9);`...? I feel the example in your question is a bit too simplified. What are you actually trying to do here? What real problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Tunaki: yes, it is just a pseudo-code. My question is more general: how to accumulate the changes to an immutable object within a stream and get the final result.

Comment: You can use `reduce` (after `.boxed()`), but since the stream can be parallel, you would have to provide a way to combine 2 `ImmutableObject`s (or just alwasy throw in the combiner, but that seems like a bad idea).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect example of streams not being the answer to everything.

However, if you insists, here is a stream version, using `collect()` on a "holder" object, so the reference value can be updated.

It's a hack, it's ugly, but it'll work.

To make it an MCVE, I created a simple immutable sum implementation.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImmutableObject o = IntStream.range(0, 10).collect(
                () -> new ImmutableObject[] { new ImmutableObject(0) },
                (h, i) -> h[0] = h[0].changeState(i),
                (h1, h2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel not supported"); }
        )[0];
        System.out.println(o); // prints: 45
    }
}

class ImmutableObject {
    private final int v;
    ImmutableObject(int v) { this.v = v; }
    ImmutableObject changeState(int i) { return new ImmutableObject(this.v + i); }
    @Override public String toString() { return Integer.toString(this.v); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I asked the question out of pure curiosity, and luckily it is not mandatory to use streams/lambdas in this case. Think, I will be going the old way.

Comment: Mutable reduction for an immutable object… If you go the route of using a throwing combiner, you can use `reduce`, which works with immutable objects naturally: `IntStream.range(0, 10).boxed() .reduce(new ImmutableObject(), ImmutableObject::changeState, (io1,io2) -> { throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Parallel not supported"); });`. Still, proceeding with such incomplete operation is not recommended. The API doesn’t specify that combiners are never used in sequential contexts.

Comment: @Holger And since `ImmutableObject` doesn't have a combiner, and likely can't get one, Streams should not be used. As I initially stated: *This is a perfect example of streams not being the answer to everything.*

Comment: We agree on that. I just didn’t want to post the simpler `reduce` code without such a disclaimer. To emphasize that we agree on that premise. That why the statement starts with “still…”.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this step by step. First replace loop with stream.

```
private static Immutable immutable = new Immutable(0);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> {
            Immutable localImmutable = immutable.changeState(i);
            System.out.println(localImmutable.toString());
        });
}
```

it executes for i in 1..10 since [range()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) has exclusive upper bound.

Next u want store reference to new instance of Immutable (ImmutableObject in your code). You can access in lambda (or any java closure in wider sense) only final (or effectively final) variables. Maybe you have heard that each lambda (or closure) has reference to its context. We can use this context to access static fields. Let's try it

```
private static Immutable immutable = new Immutable(0);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> {
            immutable = immutable.changeState(i);
            System.out.println(immutable.toString());
        });
}
```

Since context cannot change its effective final (in some languages - like groovy - you can choose different context by setting proper delegate). Last but not least lets get rid of static keyword. I ended up with example

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Test {
    private static class Immutable {
        private static int counter = 0;
        private final int id = ++counter;

        private final int state;

        public Immutable(int state) {
            this.state = state;
        }

        public Immutable changeState(int i) {
            return new Immutable(i);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "id: " + id + ", state: " + state;
        }
    }

    private Immutable immutable = new Immutable(0);
    public void run() {
        IntStream.range(0,10).forEach(i -> {
                immutable = immutable.changeState(i);
                System.out.println(immutable.toString());
            });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test().run();
    }
}
```

If you want to loose the private field you can use instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<Immutable> last = IntStream.range(0,10).boxed()
        .map(Immutable::new)
        .reduce((a,b) -> b);

    System.out.println(last.get());
}
```

Comment: `range(1,11)` is not the same as `for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)`. Also, replacing one for loop with another is not really using streams.

Comment: @Andreas: I understand 'using streams' as formulating what to do with data abstracted as Stream<?>, using these 'functional' methods like filter, map, collect, forEach etc available in Stream<?> interface. That's what I've done. In this case it looks like loop replacement but all you need is replace 'cold' source (IntStream) to 'hot' one and you operate on anything. That level of abstraction is 'using streams' in my opinion.

Comment: @lord.didger: thanks, I appreciate your time for answering but my example is just an illustration for a much more general question. I don't need to iterate over any integers or whatsoever. Please, have a look at the edited title.